# how to add features like google classroom on application flutter dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart

ask , how to add feature add room absent user on flutter dart just like google classroom.
We can add classes or rooms using keys so that data and classes cannot be accessed by other people

I am very confused in overcoming it, I try to use a table but there are limitations when i try to add a room as a table in one database.

I remember Google's application, namely Google Classromm, where we only create classes or add new classes, our data cannot be retrieved, access by others even if the application is open at the same time

please help me to finished my problem , i am very appreciate your help